# Append a list to itself in Perl

Tags: perl, list, reference

I'm still new to Perl so forgive me. I thought this would be an easy task, but for some reason I can't get the results I want. If I have a variable called `ParamRepeat` equal to 4 and an array called `Params` containing `[A,B]` how would I get `[A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B]`?

I tried many things including :

```
    my @paParam;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $ParamRepeat; $i++)
    {
        my @Params = $self->{mpaParam};
        push (@paParam,@Params);
    }
    return @paParam
```

but the output is `[[A,B],[0],[0],[0]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to know the repetition operator `x` yet:

```
my @params = qw(A B);
my $param_repeat = 4;
@params = (@params) x $param_repeat;
say "@params"; # "A B A B A B A B"
```

The parens at `(@param) x ...` are *not* optional, else, the `x` does string repetition, which evaluates `@param` in scalar context, giving the length (result: `2222`).

---

The problem in your code is that `$self->{mpaParam}` holds an *array reference*, not an array. Assigning it to an array results in an array that holds an array reference in the first field. You need to *dereference* the arrayref:

```
my @Params = @{ $self->{mpaParam} };
```

The `@{ ... }` is the array dereference operator. Then you code works as well, although I would have written the loop a bit simpler:

```
push @paParam, @{ $self->{mpaParam} } for 1 .. $ParamRepeat;
```

Note that I do not use the intermediate `@Params` variable, and that I use a `foreach` loop as a *statement modifier* (i.e. after the statement). It is equivalent to

```
for (1 .. $ParamRepeat)
  push @paParam, @{ $self->{mpaParam} };
}
```

This type of loop is a foreach-loop, in contrast to the C-style `for (X;Y;Z) { ... }` loop. For a foreach-loop, the parens after the `for` hold a list; in this case the range from `1` to `$ParamRepeat`. In Perl, the keywords `for` and `foreach` have no actual difference.

The

```
X for 1 .. $n;
```

can be read “`$n` times, do `X`”.

Answer (score 2):

`$self->{mpaParam}` contains a reference to an array.

```
my $Params = $self->{mpaParam};
```

You want the elements of the referenced array

```
@$Params
```

So

```
my $Params = $self->{mpaParam};
push @paParam, @$Params;
```

or

```
push @paParam, @{ $self->{mpaParam} };
```

---

Simpler:

```
my @paParam;
my @Params = @{ $self->{mpaParam} };  # Do this once
for (my $i = 0; $i < $ParamRepeat; $i++) {
   push @paParam, @Params;
}
return @paParam;
```

Simpler:

```
my @paParam;
my @Params = @{ $self->{mpaParam} };
for (1..$ParamRepeat) {  # Simpler loop
   push @paParam, @Params;
}
return @paParam;
```

Simpler:

```
my @Params = @{ $self->{mpaParam} };
return map { @Params } 1 .. $ParamRepeat;  # Build a list directly
```

Simpler:

```
return ( @{ $self->{mpaParam} } ) x $ParamRepeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with arrays.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @Params = ('A', 'B');
my $ParamRepeat = 4;
my @paParam;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $ParamRepeat; $i++) {
    push @paParam, @Params;
}

print "@paParam\n";
```